# Procedure? keyword in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am new to functional programming and I have a piece of code like the following:

```
(procedure? (car (list cdr)))
Value: #t
```

I do not understand why this returns true. cdr is a procedure, but what is the car of the list cdr? I do not understand. Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` turns its contents into a list. So `(list cdr)` is just a list of the element `cdr`, which itself is a procedure. `car` gets the first element of a list. So `(car (list x)) == x` for any `x`.

This simplifies our problem to `(procedure? cdr)`. Since `cdr` is clearly a procedure, this returns true.